# Symbolic link not working in chef recipe (vagrant/debian8)

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to write a Chef recipe to enable a site in nginx, and the symbolic link its creating doesn't seem to be working. The machine I'm provisioning is a Debian8 VM which I'm managing with vagrant.

This is my (very simplistic) recipe:

```rb
include_recipe 'apt'

package 'nginx' do
  action :install
  version '1.6.2-5+deb8u4'
end

service 'nginx' do
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end

cookbook_file '/etc/nginx/sites-available/corner-house.conf' do
    source 'corner-house.conf'
    mode '0644'
end

cookbook_file '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' do
    source 'nginx.conf'
    mode '0644'
end

link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/corner-house.conf' do
    to 'etc/nginx/sites-available/corner-house.conf'
end

link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default' do
  action :delete
end

file '/var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html' do
    action :delete
end

service 'nginx' do
    action :restart
end
```

And if I `ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` after running vagrant provision I see that the symlink is orphaned. If I then delete it and create a new symlink with ln -s everything works perfectly.

Am I doing something horribly wrong here or is this an issue with the vagrant + chef + debian8 combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part contains a typo: the path lacks a leading `/`:

```
to 'etc/nginx/sites-available/corner-house.conf'
```

So it must be

```
link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/corner-house.conf' do
    to '/etc/nginx/sites-available/corner-house.conf'
end
```

Comment: That's what I get for staring at the problem for too long. Thanks for saving me from myself!